# Programing Threads and handlers in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

i have executed the following code

```
public class Activity_Threads_Handler extends Activity {


private int mSec;

TextView tv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    startHeavyDutyStuff();
}

void startHeavyDutyStuff() {

    // Here is the heavy-duty thread
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {

                    mSec = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    // Send update to the main thread
                    messageHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(
                            messageHandler, mSec));

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    t.start();
}

// Instantiating the Handler associated with the main thread.
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        tv.setText(msg.what);
    }

};
```

}

the above code is to display the current second on to a TextView continually updating it ...

and i got the following error in my logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #x22
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
>   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
>   at com.kpj4s.Threads_Handler.Activity_Threads_Handler$1.handleMessage(Activity_Threads_Handler.java:56)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

can some one help me out pls ..
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView.setText(int)` expects the integer parameter to be a resource identifier. You need to convert it to a `String`, i.e. you want:

```
tv.setText(Integer.toString(msg.what));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is:

```
tv.setText(msg.what);
```

What are you trying to do?

The problem is that `msg.what` is an integer and `setText` receives: either a `String` or an integer that is an android resource (for instance R.string.something). Thus, if you want to show the `msg.what` content use `tv.setText(String.valueOf(msg.what))` instead.